# Github Actions First deploy on Kubernetes

Tags: github, kubernetes, github-actions, kubectl

I have this Github Actions, to deploy on K8S.

This display works perfect. Update the container with the build version, based on the SHA | ${{ github.sha }}. My query is How do I do an apply, for the first time? When the manifest was never deployed.

```
    name: Deploy to cluster
    uses: myrotvorets/kubectl-action@2.0.0
    with:
      config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
      version: latest
      args: set image --record deployment/app-deploy app-deploy=APITEST/app:${{ github.sha }}
  - 
    name: Verify deployment
    uses: myrotvorets/kubectl-action@2.0.0
    with:
      config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
      version: latest
      args: '"rollout status deployment/app-deploy"'
```

Can you help me?

It is possible to put a condition "if the cluster is not deployed, then apply the manifest".

Answer (score -1):

you can include the $tag to the image section on your manifest